# Include value of submit button on forms

Tags: php, forms

I have two submit buttons in a form which has different values, one to voteup a post and another to votedown a post, how do i submit the value of the `input type="submit"` buttons?

`Without using javascript`, i'm making my script flexible to browsers with javascript disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST)) {
var_dump($_POST);
}

echo '
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="vote_up" value="up">
<input type="submit" name="vote_down" value="down">
</form>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of the clicked button will always be submitted with the form. This is how you can disambiguate between different submit buttons on the same form.

Further clarification can be found at: http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/html-form-submit.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Just include it into the form you are submitting and do something like this for disambiguate the buttons:

```
 <input class="submitButton" type="submit" name="up" id="up">
```

Then in your code you can do something like:

```
if (isset($_POST["up"])){ 
 // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
print_r($_POST);
```

in place of

```
var_dump($_POST);
```